# $on event, set a variable to true

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope, dom-events

This is a dumb scoping issue and I'm bad at Javascript.  Pretty sure I don't know how to return the value of a variable up to parent scope (e.g. look for the **** in `AppCtrl`)

I have 2 controllers.  `AppCtrl (parent)` and `MainCtrl (child)`

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  </div>
</div>
```

I am fetching some random JSON data in the `MainCtrl`.

```
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

        $scope.datas = [];
        $http.jsonp('http://filltext.com/?rows=10&delay=1&fname={firstName}&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').
            success(function(data){
                $scope.datas[0] = data;
                console.log($scope.datas);
                $scope.$emit('load::1');
        });
        $http.jsonp('http://filltext.com/?rows=10&delay=2&fname={firstName}&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').
            success(function(data){
                $scope.datas[1] = data;
                console.log($scope.datas);
                $scope.$emit('load::2');
        });
        $http.jsonp('http://filltext.com/?rows=10&delay=4&fname={firstName}&callback=JSON_CALLBACK').
            success(function(data){
                $scope.datas[2] = data;
                console.log($scope.datas);
                $scope.$emit('load::3');
        });
      });
```

When that data is successful I will emit a message to `AppCtrl`.

On the `AppCtrl` I am listening for the emitted messages and setting the array `var load = true`.

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    //*****
    var load = [];
    $scope.$on('load::1', function(){
        //how do i return this value to the var above?
        load[0] = true;
    });
    $scope.$on('load::2', function(){
        load[1] = true;

    });
    $scope.$on('load::3', function(){
        load[2] = true;
    });


    if(load[0]=== true && load[1] === true && load[2] == true) {
        console.log('loaded');
    }
});
```

when all three  are set to true I would like the `console.log` to log out `'loaded'`.

Comment: I think you should use return load[0] = true; in all $scope.on functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If condition will run only once so you can call if condition with every $on listener or  combine multiple listener and check if all content is loaded or not.both ways are same.

```
myapp.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
//*****
 var load = [];
 angular.forEach(['load::1', 'load::2', 'load::3'], function (value) {
    $scope.$on(value, function (event) {
        load.push(true);
        if (load[0] === true && load[1] === true && load[2] == true) {
            alert('loaded');
        }
    });
 });
});
```

[***Fiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/k3H4Q/)

Answer (score 0):

1. It will never print 'loaded' because this statement run only once

`if(load[0]=== true && load[1] === true && load[2] == true) {
        console.log('loaded');
    }`

2. To share data between controllers in Angular is better to use services https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services.